# Debugging the error in the line graph and scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot to variables against each other on both a line graph and a scatter plot separately but keep getting the same error.

I have imported everything that need correctly here:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
#import geopandas as gp 
%matplotlib inline
```

Link to the data frame is here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/abecklas/fifa-world-cup?datasetId=19728&sortBy=voteCount&select=WorldCups.csv

Here is the snippet of the line graph and scatter plot code and error:

```
df20.plot(kind = 'scatter', x = 'Year', y = 'GoalsScored')
df20.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'Year', y = 'GoalsScored')
```

I think its trying to tell me that the column doesnt exist?

Error code:

```
  ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Year'
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of code/data/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8881141). Post the formatted text directly here on SO.

Comment: Apologies, would you like me to edit the query again so that you can have direct access to the text?

Comment: Yes, you should always edit the question when adding information or code. In general, you should provide [a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including sample data as text. Nobody wants to type information from an image.

Comment: Yup, that's what `KeyError` means. Maybe it is "year" or " Year", something you don't immediately see when checking `df20.info`. How did you import the data?

Comment: I have tried both Year and year and it still throws an error. I have imported the data through pandas as I had the csv downloaded locally. I saved it to the df20 that you see me using right now.


        df20 = pd.read_csv("WorldCups.csv", index_col = 0)

Comment: `index_col = 0` sets "Year" as the index - the index is not a column. Try again after removing this.

Comment: thanks that worked. Can't believe I overlooked something this small. I need to make sure my indexing is correct from now on